# Powershell - Need to recognize if there is more than one result (regex)

Tags: powershell

I am using this to find if file name contains exactly 7 digits

```
if ($file.Name -match '\D(\d{7})(?:\D|$)') {
    $result = $matches[1]
}
```

The problem is when there is a file name that contains 2 groups of 7 digits
for an example:

```
patch-8.6.22 (1329214-1396826-Increase timeout.zip
```

In this case the result will be the first one (1329214).
For most cases there is only one number so the regex is working but I must to recognize if there is more than 1 group and integrated into the if ()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- The [`-match`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Comparison_Operators#-match-and--notmatch) operator only ever looks for *one* match.
- To get *multiple* ones, you must currently use the underlying .NET APIs directly, specifically [`[regex]::Matches()`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Matches):

  - Note: There's a green-lighted proposal to implement a `-matchall` operator, but as of PowerShell 7.3.0 it hasn't been implemented yet - see [GitHub issue #7867](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/7867).

```bash
# Sample input.
$file = [pscustomobject] @{ Name = 'patch-8.6.22 (1329214-1396826-Increase timeout.zip' }

# Note: 
# * If *nothing* matches, $result will contain $null
# * If *one* substring matches, return will be a single string.
# * If *two or more* substrings match, return will be an *array* of strings.
$result = ([regex]::Matches($file.Name, '(?<=\D)\d{7}(?=\D|$)')).Value
```

- [`.Value`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Text.RegularExpressions.Match.Value) uses [member-access enumeration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Member-Access_Enumeration) to extract matching substrings, if any, from the elements of the collection returned by `[regex]::Matches()`.
- I've tweaked the regex to use *lookaround assertions* (`(?<=/...)` and `(?=...)`) so that only the substrings of interest are captured.

  - See [this regex101.com page](https://regex101.com/r/rPGjtQ/1) for an explanation of the regex and the ability to experiment with it.

Comment: Thank you @mklement(). there is a reason why the file name is pscustom object?
Can I use this also for get a 7 digit number from "\\XXXXXX.com\global\Patch Managment\1399771\" right? 
I don't familiar with the lookaround assertions you added ands will be happy for more explanation what it does and why the original ?:\ replaced with ?=

Comment: My pleasure, @Bandit. `[pscustomobject]` was just used as a placeholder for the `[System.IO.FileInfo]` instances as output by `Get-ChildItem` that I presume you'll be working with.  Yes, ``\\XXXXXX.com\global\Patch Managment\1399771\`` should work too (if the number is in the _parent directory's path_ rather than in the file _name_, you'll have to match against `.FullName`). The linked rege101.com page explains the regex in detail, but in short: `(?<=...)` looks _behind_ (to the left), without including what the subexpression matches in the match, and `(?=...)` looks _ahead_ (to the right).

Comment: Thanks
Why not like this: '(?<=\D)\d{7}(?=:\D|$)' 
In the original regex was ":"why I don't need it anymore?

Comment: As you can see the web is not working for me https://regex101.com/r/8DLQXC/1

Comment: @Bandit, your regex has a _trailing newline_, that's why it's not working on regex101.com. You can verify that the regex from this answer works with your other sample input as well as follows: `[regex]::Matches('Patch_1399771 + 1254877 ', '(?<=\D)\d{7}(?=\D|$)').Value`. As for `:` - `(?:...)` is an unrelated construct it is a _non-capturing group_.  You don't need it, if you use a lookahead assertion instead.

Comment: Thank you @mklement()
I am wondering why I need both looks behind and ahead if the match starts from left to right

Comment: @Bandit: The look-behind assertion ensures that no digit _precedes_ your 7-digit run, and the look-ahead assertion ensures that none _follows_ it.